# Are there video rewarded ads networks without company requirement?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have googled some of the video rewarded ads networks and all of them require a company name to register. I am an induvidual without a company and I want to display video rewarded ads in my app if its possible. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company name is optional. I generally put the developer/user name (using which i publish my apps) or just `Self`.